# Optimistic Concurrency in Model First Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, optimistic-concurrency

I'm having difficulty getting this to work.

I have a `product` table with a `version` column that is of type binary fixed length 8, `ConcurrencyMode=fixed`, `nullable=false`, `store generated pattern = computed`.

Now when I update a `product` entity in the code I don't see this `version` column incremented. I don't see how to make the type of it `timestamp` in the database unless I change it in there directly or fiddle about with the metadata for the entity, but then I thought it would be enough to set "store generated pattern". I just want this to work with model first approach setting the properties of the field as mentioned.

My C# code is :

```
_db = new ProductsContext();

_db.Products.Load();

try
{ 
    using (var db2 = new ProductsContext())
    {
        db2.Products.Load();

        Product p2 = db2.Products.Find(3);
        p2.quantity = 2;

        db2.SaveChanges();
    }

    Product p = _db.Products.Find(3);
    p.quantity = 3;

    _db.SaveChanges();
}
catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
{
    string a = "";
}
```

I don't see the exception caught if I run it in debug mode. Thank you.

Ok I found another question with a similar thing being asked and someone on there said to change the database generation template...

[Concurrency timestamp column stays null with computed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639737/concurrency-timestamp-column-stays-null-with-computed)

I assume this is the best way of doing this as the functionality by default doesn't seem to be there. Thankyou for your replies.

Comment: What is the **table structure** in your database? In order for the column to be used as a "concurrency token", it **must be** of type `timestamp` or `rowversion` - anything else doesn't work.

Comment: The type of that column I set in the properties for that model in the designer as binary. In the drop-down there is no option for timestamp or rowversion. This seems strange to me that by version 6 of this thing that is not possible. Is that the case? Where do I set the type of this column to timestamp or rowversion then? In the database after I generate it from the model? Doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: Wait, you're working database-first right? (Since you're talking about "metadata for the entity"). That means you're *supposed* to change the column type in the database.

Comment: No model-first as it says in the title. I mentioned metadata as that would be the only other option unless I change the database after I generate it from the model.

Comment: An [inconvenient truth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3184628) for EF4. Not sure how much of this is still required, but Model First isn't developed so actively anymore.

Comment: What about EF6?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with editing a t4 template. In EF6 it's still the same.

Comment: What is the type of the column in the **database**?  If you are doing model first, the **database** is what matters first.  (Not the EF property type of binary.)